# How can I choice data is put to model or one is not do to it?

Tags: python, django, excel

I wanna parse excel and put data in the model(User). views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row(row_index)  
  print(rows[1]) 

for row in rows:
  user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], 
              name=rows[4])
  user.save()
```

Excel is 
[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4iMr.png)

I do not want to put data of row whose user_id & name column is empty.In this case,I do not want to put data of line 5 & 6 .But now, my code is to put all excel data to User model.I cannot understand how to extract excel data and put to model.What should I do to do so?I thought if content of list is empty, the data should be skipped.But list is not separate each content, for example `[1,1,40,Tom]` can be counted 1 list.

Comment: why cant you simply check if that column is empty or not ?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar i wanna know how to do it.If u write code, how do u write it?

Comment: `print(rows[1]) ` gives you the complete row? Never worked with Excel but I would try `rows[1][0]` or similar. Check out this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480449/reading-particular-cell-value-from-excelsheet-in-python . He used `value = worksheet.cell(row, column)` to get the specific value. Next step would be `if value: add row` for two value checks use the `and` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code after getting each row, check if its empty or not. like this :

```
for row in rows:
     if row[1] != '' and row[2] != '':
          user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3],name=rows[4])
          user.save()
```