# import excel with pandas using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Python and a have a problem.
I'm trying to import an excel file with pandas and I'm using VS Code.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Python\user.xlsx')
print(data)
```

I already installed `xlrd`, but however I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\import-excel.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Python\user.xlsx')
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 170, in open_workbook
    raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: try changing the engine arg `pd.read_excel(r'D:\Python\user.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: thank you @Manakin but already done and got another error:  **ValueError: Unknown engine: <module 'openpyxl' from 'D:\\Python\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\openpyxl\\__init__.py'>**

Comment: you might need to install `openpyxl` first `pip install openypyxl` see the dupe for others with that issue, seems to be quite a big breaking change

Comment: Ahhhh i saw it. i wrote engine=openpyxl instead of engine = 'openpyxl' :-))) also without **''**. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As noted by other members, xlrd has discontinued support for formats other than .xls.

Recommended is to use another library such as [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

As suggested by user Chris Withers in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266270/13170538):

1. Install openpyxl: `pip install openpyxl`
2. Implement your code as:

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   data = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Python\user.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

   print(data)
   ```

Hope this works for you!