# XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported Databricks

Tags: python, excel, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Databricks and trying to read an excel file. I have an encrypted file with `.xlsx.pgp`.  After decrypting the message I get it as a byte array. So, here's the function I use to read this file as a pandas dataframe:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(orig))
```

However, this is giving me the following error:

`XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported`

Now, based on [this](https://kb.databricks.com/libraries/xlsx-file-not-supported-xlrd.html) documentation:

I have added openpyxl to the cluster and then tried to run the following:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(orig),engine=`openpyxl`)
```

I'm getting the error:

`global name 'openpyxl' is not defined`

With the following command, I get:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(orig),engine='openpyxl')
```

The error I get is:

`ValueError: Unknown engine: openpyxl`

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors suggests that, `openpyxl` library is not properly installed. Also maybe notebook is not in scope of `openpyxl` library.

Please install `openpyxl` in Cluster which is attached to notebook as shown below:

**Step1:** Select Cluster and click on `libraries`.
[image]

**Step2:**  Click on `Install New`.

Next click on `PyPI`.

Now enter name of library that is `openpyxl`

Then click on `Install`.

[image]

**Step3:** Check status of openpyxl library is installed.

[image]

**Step4:**  Successfully installed openpyxl library.

[image]

---

**Edit -**

> **Note -** pandas version should be  1.0.1 or above.

If pandas version is below 1.0.1, you can upgrade pandas library using `pip install pandas`

Check pandas version using `pd.__version__` command.

For more information you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65304612) from rama-a

Comment: I had done this already but still facing the same issue. I also found that the version for pandas is 0.19.2 while the version of xlrd is 2.0.1 so maybe that's why openpyxl is not working.

Comment: @jukebox, I have Updated answer, Please check.