# Trying to import an excel into the database using python xlrd package gives an error: XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Tags: python, xlrd

I tried to open the excel using the code given below:

```
loc="/Users/shruti/Downloads/user.xlsx"
wb=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
```

I get the following error.

```
XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: [xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) is a library for reading data and formatting information from Excel files in the historical **.xls** format. use other libs such as *openpyxl*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254535/xlrd-biffh-xlrderror-excel-xlsx-file-not-supported)